# Count items that have diff formatting with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am confused how to count items that are the same but have different formatting. E.g we want to know how many different fruits people have and have the following data:

```
Mary|Apple|
Mary|apple|
Mary|Apple |
Mary|Orange|
Liu|Grape|
Liu|Apple|
```

I expect the output

```
Mary|2
Liu|2
```

But if I do `count(distinct fruits)` then I get

```
Mary|4
Liu|2
```

If there any way to deal with formatting in this case?

Comment: `Mary|Apple |` <-- is this space part of your actual data, or just a formatting error?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen space is part of a data, I want to get rid of space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count them:

- Removing initial and trailing spaces - use `TRIM()`.
- Removing the letter case - use `LOWER()`.

As in:

```
select
    name,
    count(distinct lower(trim(fruits))) 
  from my_table
  group by name
```

You could use the same strategy with the `name` column if it happens to have similar irregularities.

Answer (score 2):

Take the distinct count of the lowercase version of the fruit names:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT LOWER(TRIM(fruit))) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    name;
```

### Demo

The demo is in MySQL, but the same logic should work in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` is not the only tool here. You can use `GROUP BY` with a normalized version of the column text to combine all the different casings and trailing spaces into one. For example:

```
SELECT name, fruit, count(fruit) AS cnt
FROM test
GROUP BY name, trim(upper(fruit));
```

gives me

```
name        fruit       cnt       
----------  ----------  ----------
Liu         Apple       1         
Liu         Grape       1         
Mary        Apple       3         
Mary        Orange      1
```

However, it looks like you want the total number of different types of fruit per person. So...

```
WITH totals(name, fruit) AS
  (SELECT name, fruit
   FROM test
   GROUP BY name, trim(upper(fruit)))
SELECT name, count(fruit) AS fruits
FROM totals
GROUP BY name;
```

gives me

```
name        fruits    
----------  ----------
Liu         2         
Mary        2
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `DISTINCT` is often implemented using `GROUP BY` under the hood.